# Arduino timer interrupt sampling

Tags: c, timer, arduino, interrupt, atmega

I'm using an Arduino Mini Pro and I'm using it to sample the data line of a C218D 433Mhz rf receiver. When using timer interrupts, the Arduino seems to miss most of the samples. However when using delays instead, it seems to work perfectly fine! Problem is, is that I cannot use delays for my project and need to use the timer interrupts. Is there some problem with Arduino interrupts?

The problem persists even when I'm using delays but have interrupts enabled, even if they aren't doing anything!

Comment: can you upload your code so we can see it? It would help us analyze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think i solved it, Serial port was open and messing with my interupts